# how to write cypress locator for this specific button which is next to the text 'Dont words' on webpage

Tags: cypress

how to write cypress locator for this specific button which is next to the text 'Dont words' on webpage. please see attached screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `parent()` and `within()` to find your button based on the text.

```js
cy.contains('span', 'Dont-words')
  .parent() //goes to div.jss680
  .parent() //goes to span.jss687
  .parent() //goes to div.jss686
  .parent() //goes to fieldset
  .parent() //goes to div.Mui-expanded
  .next() //goes to div.MuiCollapse-root
  .within(() => { //next commands are scoped to div.MuiCollapse-root
    cy.get('li').eq(1).find('button').should('be.visible')
  })
```